# Error of characters in PDF Polish language

Tags: android, pdf, character-encoding, itext

I am generating PDF on android for the language of Poland with the iText library, version 2 (`com.lowagie`). The problem is that the characters are wrong. Can anyone help me? How do I display the correct character from Poland in PDF?

Comment: Which font do you use?

Comment: What method are you using to write the text?

Comment: I'm using the standard library, utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Font fontNormal = FontFactory.getFont((winfontpath), encoding,BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10, Font.NORMAL);
Chunk chunkpoland = new Chunk("hai welcome", fontNormal);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(chunkpoland ));
winfontpath=C:\\windows\\fonts\\SimHei.ttf
```

This is chinees font but you can assign polish font path